# My image in my PyGame program isn't loading

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a flappy bird program in Pygame, and I'm trying to add a gameover image when the bird collides with something. It isn't working, how can I fix it?

```
if (pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, ground_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) or
                        pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, pipe_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)):
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(hit)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    time.sleep(1)

                    GAMEOVER = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/gameover.png')
                    GAMEOVER = pygame.transform.scale(GAMEOVER, (0,0))
                    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't painting the image to the screen/window, just loading and re-scaling the `gameover.png` bitmap.

Even if the code did draw that bitmap, it's exiting immediately with the `quit()` so the user would never have time to see it.

The game should run in a continual loop, and not `quit()` at the end of the game.   One way to implement this is sort of logic is to define a set of game states.   This might be something like: "menu", "playing" and "gameover".

In your main screen-updating loop, use the current state to work out what should be done.  Obviously in "gameover" mode, the code would just paint the `gameover.png` bitmap to the screen (rather than showing the start menu, or running the game).